# RTC merge issue after resolving conflicts using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, merge, rtc

I am very new to  RTC source management and recently started using it in my project. Currently i am stuck with an issue for which i could not find any proper answer may be i am missing something below is the description of problem. kindly bear with me for the detailed description. I am using the Eclipse 3.x bundled with STS for development.

There was an incoming changeset which contained a file say processemail.java which had  conflicting changes with the processemail.java version i had in my workspace. I accepted that change and later a red arrow started appearing on the file in my unresolved changes. I tried to auto resolve but RTC threw error that cannot auto resolve use manual resolve.

So i did a manual merge of the file using the compare editor and clicked the mark as resolve button to resolve it.Red arrow gone and My workspace contained merged file. After this a new changeset by the name "Merges" appeared automatically in my outgoing changes which contained this merged file version.

Later i had to do some additional code change in processemail.java which i did and it appeared in Unresolved changes. Now when i try to add the updated version of processemail.java to a brand new change set along with other related files RTC throws error stating cannot create a new change set let the file decide which change set to use. If i select the processemail.java in the unresolved changes it is getting highlighted with a Blue color and the Merges in my outgoing also gets highlighted with that.

I am not sure what to do now. Should i add the file to the Merges changeset that got created automatically which i did not try or what will happen if this possible will the version in the Merges get updated with this modified version of processemail.java. i also have other files along with this change what should my approach be. Can anybody please help me with their suggestion on this. been stuck with this issue for a long time now.

Thanks

Vikeng21

Comment: what is the *exact* error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what will happen if this possible will the version in the Merges get updated with this modified version of `processemail.java`

Yes, but that won't matter, as long as that allows you to proceed with other checkins (and ultimately with a deliver)

Comment: thanks for the reply. do you mean to say that i can checkin other set of files to the Merges change set along with updated processemail.java and complete the changeset.

Comment: @vikeng21 you can, but it isn't the recommended practice. Try and add only the file RTC is complaining about (again, having the *exact* error message would help here). There rest can be checked in in new change sets.

Comment: dude you are awesome. thank you so much for helping me. accepted your answer